# Listener method inside auto-binding template? (Polymer 1.0)

Tags: javascript, ajax, polymer, polymer-1.0

```
<template is="dom-bind">
    <custom-element></custom-element>
    <iron-ajax auto url="data.json" handle-as="json" last-response="{{data}}" on-response="receivedResponse"></iron-ajax>
</template>
```

In the example above "custom-element" needs to know when iron-ajax has received a response. The problem is that I don't know where to put the "receivedResponse" method. How do I do this? I prefer to put it inside "custom-element", but then I don't know how to bind it to the "on-response" event of iron-ajax.

I could bind the "{{data}}" to a property of "custom-element" and have an observer for that property, but that feels like a hack and I'd like to find out the correct way of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assign a id to the auto-binding template for ease of access

```
<tempalte id="app" is="dom-bind">
```

Then init the template in Javascript

```
var app = document.querySelector('#app');
```

and create the function.

```
app.receivedResponse = function () {
  // process response
}
```

in cases where you need to wait for all polymer elements to be stamped to the dom you wait for the 'dom-change' event

```
app.addEventListener('dom-change', function () {
  // dom is ready to work with
});
```

hope this helps...

Comment: Thank you, this is what I needed! So if you bind a function to a property within a template, it will try to call the function on the template. Like if you do that within an element template it will call the function on the element. Makes sense now!

Answer (score -2):

`<custom-element data="{{data}}"></custom-element>`

Comment: Down voting because this is exactly what I was not looking for. Please see the last sentence of my question. Thanks for the answer anyway!